# Описание или рассуждение?

Tags: стилистика

Разработчики теста ЕГЭ (Статград) утверждают, что этот отрывок - повествование:

(39) Значит, Ленка всю вину взяла на себя. (40) А он, старый
леший, даже не подумал об этом. (41) Кажется, она сможет прожить свою жизнь
не хуже прочих Бессольцевых, ибо обладала теми чудесными качествами
характера, которые непременно требовали от неё участия в судьбах людей и
боли за них.

Answer (score 1):

А Вы уверены, что поняли задание? Там требовалось
найти ошибочное утверждение, а это явно рассуждение, не ошибка.

Comment: Вопрос: найти ошибочные варианты.
в задании:
3) предл. 39-41 - рассуждение

Comment: А где ответы? На каком сайте? Почему Вы утверждаете, что у них ошибка в ответах? дело в том, что Вы могли что-то не понять. Мне знаком тест, дети выполняли, никакой ошибки не зафиксировали

Comment: Лучше приведете ссылку. Хотя задание мне не знакомо, но, скорее всего, Людмила права: обычно требуется найти ошибочное утверждение. Я попытался найти это задание в интернете - не смог.

Comment: "в задании: 3) предл. 39-41 - рассуждение". Это и есть, наверное, ошибочный вариант.

Comment: У вас есть возможность дать ссылку?

Comment: Если это КИМ № 9176:
1) В предл. 11−12 содер. описание.-верно
2) В предл 1−2  повествование.-ошибка, здесь рассуждение(1)Ленка стояла перед дедушкой, маленькая, худенькая, еле сдерживая слёзы. (2)Николай Николаевич Бессольцев ждал, когда она наберётся сил рассказать о том, что тревожит её, он понимал, что одно неосторожно сказанное слово − и внучка замкнётся в себе. 
3) В предл 39−41  рассуждение.-верно
4) Предл 32 противопоставлено по содерж. предл 31.-верно
5) Предл. 17−20  повествование-ошибка, рассуждениение

Comment: С другой стороны, в задании 21 всегда 3 ответа, значит, должна быть ещё ошибка. Но я уверена, что в предл.39-41 рассуждение.Это МЫСЛИ деда, их нельзя зафиксировать на фото или слайде, а повествование - последовательность действий, которые можно зафиксировать на нескольких слайдах.

Comment: Людмила, в предложении 39-41 действительно рассуждение. Если это тот тест, то в ответах все правильно. Почему автор засомневался?

Comment: Я не знаю ключи к  ответу, но Вы видите, кто-то сказал, что в ключах повествование.

Comment: Да, наверное ошибка.